# If I change the email address that we use in our PHPmailer, do I have to change the DKIM keys/domain as well?

Tags: php, phpmailer, dkim

We have a new email address that we would like to use in our PHPmailer. Once I changed it, it stopped working. Is there any settings or DKIM config I need to change as well?

Answer (score 0):

If your `from` address' domain doesn't match your envelope sender domain you may have trouble with DMARC alignment. You should be able to fix that by adding a DKIM selector record for the domain that you are using in your `from` address. [DKIM & DMARC diagnostic services](https://dmarc.org/resources/deployment-tools/) like Port25 or mxtoolbox will be able to give you more info on what doesn't line up.